# Python3 cannot find CUDA dll files

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

I am having an issue that when I try to use tensorflow with my gpu it says none can be found. This is the code I am running to see how many GPUs I have available

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
    
    
print("Num GPUs Available: ", len(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')))
```

The messages I am getting when I run `$ python3 main.py`are the following:

```
2021-09-04 16:52:04.477828: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_110.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_110.dll not found
2021-09-04 16:52:04.477963: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.
2021-09-04 16:52:07.179742: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_110.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_110.dll not found
...
2021-09-04 16:52:07.182033: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1835] Cannot dlopen some GPU libraries. Please make sure the missing libraries mentioned above are installed properly if you would like to use GPU. Follow the guide at https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu for how to download and setup the required libraries for your platform.
Skipping registering GPU devices...
Num GPUs Available:  0
```

Running `$ nvcc -V` gives me

```
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2021 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Wed_Jul_14_19:47:52_Pacific_Daylight_Time_2021
Cuda compilation tools, release 11.4, V11.4.100
Build cuda_11.4.r11.4/compiler.30188945_0
```

I have followed the instructions on the tensorflow website and nvidia site. My path contains `CUDA_PATH` and `CUDA_PATH_V11_4` both pointing to `C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.4`.The `cudart64_110.dll` filw which the error message says cannot be found is in `C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.4\bin`.

I would like to know why I cannot use `python3` to run my program. I have tried all sorts of stuff and can't figure out what I am missing. Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: *It seems to work fine when I run it with `$ python main.py` or through a Jupyter notebook. It seems `$ python3 main.py` is the only case where it does not work.*

Comment: The tensorflow version  you have undoubtedly needs a different version of the CUDA runtime libraries than CUDA 11.4

Comment: Can you let us know Tensorflow version?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the list of CUDA versions working on Tensorflow-gpu versions.
https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source#linux
Checking which is install and download that version.